# JQuery - Move to next Number by DownArrow and UpArrow

Tags: jquery

Seeing the following code, the numbers are displayed with the different HTML Tag and tree structure. I would like to move Number 1 -> Number 2 -> Number 3 -> Number 4 by pressing DownArrow and move back from Number 4 -> Number 3 -> Number 2 -> Number 1 by pressing UpArrow key.

N.B. JQuery would be much more preferred!

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
<div>
    <p class="number">1</p>
</div>
<div class="number">2</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="number">3</li>
        <li class="number">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have some code what you tried?

Comment: You can try jQuery`s `slideToggle()`.Ref:http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: @Davor Mlinaric, my code $('.number')..live({
   
   keyup: function(e){
    
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    //up arrow
    if (code == '38') {
     //alert("up");
     $(this).prev().css("border","orange 2px solid");
    }
    
   },
   
   keydown: function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    //down arrow
    if (code == '40') {
     $(this).next().css("border","black 2px solid");

    }
    
   }
   
   
  });